# Angular 9 : html select does respect value in model after click

Tags: html, angular, select, angular-changedetection

I am implementing a component where in a user is asked to confirm his choice when he selects a value from an HTML select. If the user selects no, i want to revert to the older value. The reverting works and the model gets updated but the select view does not show the right value. Instead it shows the value user clicked on.
i have minimal working example here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8cybe9

I tried using changedetection as well but that too doesnt help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `select` element displays the value selected in the list, which is the normal behavior of the browser. And since the model value has not changed, Angular does not see any reason to update the element. To trigger such an update and put back the previous value, we must force Angular to detect a change, even when that change was cancelled afterwards. Here is one way to do it:

1. Set the model property to the new value
2. Call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` to force change detection
3. Restore the previous value in the model property
4. Optionally: call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` again to prevent flicker

```js
updateMetric(currentVal, prevVal) {
  this.currentVal = currentVal;
  this.preVal = prevVal;
  this.model.rating = currentVal;             // <-- set new value
  if (window.confirm("Proceed?")) {
    this.currentVal = currentVal;
  } else {
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();   // <-- force change detection
    this.model.rating = prevVal;              // <-- restore previous value
    this.currentVal = prevVal;
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();   // <-- prevent flicker
  }
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dtaq2b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: Thank you! I assume this is because the browser updates the select to the option that was clicked on irrespective of the final value in the model. The "set new value" step makes sure that angular runtime and the browser are in sync before we make additional changes to the model. Would this be right?

Comment: @SibiJohn - That is the way I see it, yes. I added more details to my answer.